# Trying to extract the value from a drop down list of aray

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've written some code that takes each number in an array (which is dependent on a for loop) and assigns them an HTML option tag, then inserts them within a single select list. The result is an drop down menu with a range of "1" to "100.

My issue is I want to select a number from the drop down menu I've created, so I can store and or display it's value, but don't know how.

For example: Say I have an equation X * 2.I want to be able to select a number from the drop down and have X equal that value (I select 3 from the menu, then the result should be 6).

Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <select id="selectLvl">
        <option>Choose your Level:</option>   
    </select>
</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var lvlStart = 1;
var lvlEnd = 101;
var arr = [];

while (lvlStart < lvlEnd) {
    arr.push(lvlStart++)
}

var selectLvl = document.getElementById("selectLvl");
for (var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    var opt = arr[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    selectLvl.appendChild(el);        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) property can be used to get the currently selected value:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100;)
  selectLvl.add(new Option(i++))

selectLvl.onchange = function() { console.log(selectLvl.value * 2) }
```

```html
<select id=selectLvl>
  <option>Choose your Level:</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` event should do the trick.

```js
var lvlStart = 1;
var lvlEnd = 101;
var arr = [];

while (lvlStart < lvlEnd) {
    arr.push(lvlStart++)
}

var selectLvl = document.getElementById("selectLvl");
for (var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
    var opt = arr[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    selectLvl.appendChild(el);

}

selectLvl.addEventListener('change',function(){
  // Get the selected value
  var selectedLevel = this.value;
  
  // if (selectedLevel * 2) returns NaN (Not a Number), output will be 0
  var output = (selectedLevel * 2) || 0;
  
  // alert the output
  alert(output);
});
```

```html
<select id="selectLvl">
  <option>Choose your level:</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Access the `<select>` by its **id**.
- Go through a for loop and create options in it.
- Set value to every option with `setAttribute()`.
- Append it to the `<select>`.

Event

- Add `change` event to `<select>`.
- Get the **selected** **value** with

  `el.options[el.selectedIndex].value`
- Put this value as an argument in a custom function, here `double()`.
- Store this value in an array with `push()`.

**Example**
(Select a few numbers to see how it works)

```js
var level = document.getElementById("level"),
  storage = [];

function double(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

for (i = 1; i < 101; i += 1) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", i);
  option.innerHTML = i; // Or textContent
  level.appendChild(option);
}

level.addEventListener("change", function() { // Add change event
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(double(value));
  storage.push(double(value));
  alert(storage);
});
```

```html
<select id="level">
  <option>Choose your Level:</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to make it short as follows;

```
var lvlStart = 1;
var lvlEnd = 101;
var selectLvl = document.getElementById("selectLvl");

for (var i=lvlStart ; i<= lvlEnd ; i++){
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    selectLvl.appendChild(el);
}
```

Use JQuery to handle the change event

```
$('#selectLvl').change(function(){
    var x=this.value;
    var answer=Number(x)*2;
    alert('Answer= '+ answer);
});
```

Comment: i don't think jQuery is good option for OP this time, as looking on his situation, like learning at school

Comment: Thank you, but as Jacky mentioned, I'm looking to do this just in Javascript. I should've made that clearer in question.